# SQL server while loop not working. Only getting the first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, while-loop

Currently I'm creating a report to list the Deltas of each territory by month, so I can create trend lines in the end to indicate the decreasing patterns of deltas.

this is my current code that can produce the deltas for the current week. Code is extremely messy, I'm still just trying to get the right number at the moment.

```
select t0.descript as 'Territory', t0.[Current Delta] as 'Current Delta', t0.[Current Sales] as 'Current Sales', t2.[Annual Goal] as 'Total Annual Goal'
from
    (select DeltaMainTable.descript,  sum(DeltaMainTable.Delta) as 'Current Delta', Sum(DeltaMaintable.[Yearly Sales]) as "Current Sales"
    from
    (
        select isnull(datepart(ww,T3.DocDate),0) as 'weeks'
        , t2.descript
        , t0.cardcode
        , sum(isnull(sum(t3.[total Sales]),0)) over (partition by t0.cardcode order by datepart(ww,T3.DocDate)) as 'Yearly Sales'
        , cast((case when min(t0.U_CG) - sum(isnull(sum(t3.[total Sales]),0)) over (partition by t0.cardcode order by datepart(ww,T3.DocDate)) > 0 then min(t0.U_CG) - sum(isnull(sum(t3.[total Sales]),0)) over (partition by t0.cardcode order by datepart(ww,T3.DocDate)) else 0 end) as int) as 'Delta'
        from 
        OCRD T0 
        left join oter T2 on T0.territory = T2.territryID
        left join 
--------INV + RIN------Credit + Debit Calculation In Between--------------------------------------INV + RIN------------------------------------
            (select SalesTable.name as 'name', SalesTable.docdate, sum(SalesTable.[total Sales]) as 'Total Sales'
            from (
                select T0.basecard as 'name', t0.docdate, sum(T0.linetotal) as 'total Sales'
                from hmltd.dbo.inv1 t0
                left join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                where t1.U_BR = 'GPNA' and year(t0.docdate) = year(getdate()) 
                group by T0.basecard, T0.docDate
                union all
                select T0.basecard as 'name', t0.docdate, sum(t0.linetotal)*-1 as 'total Sales'
                from hmltd.dbo.rin1 t0
                left join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                where t1.U_BR = 'GPNA' and year(t0.docdate) = year(getdate()) 
                group by T0.basecard, T0.docDate
            ) SalesTable 
            group by SalesTable.name, SalesTable.DocDate
            ) T3 on T0.cardcode = T3.name
--------INV + RIN------Credit + Debit Calculation In Between--------------------------------------INV + RIN------------------------------------
        where T0.U_CRR <> '' and t0.U_CR1 = 'R'
        group by t0.cardcode , t2.descript, datepart(ww, T3.DocDate)
    )DeltaMainTable
    inner join 
    (
        select
            t0.cardcode, ISNULL(max(datepart(ww,T3.DocDate)),0) as 'maxweeks'
        from 
        OCRD T0 
        left join 
--------INV + RIN------Credit + Debit Calculation In Between--------------------------------------INV + RIN------------------------------------
            (select SalesTable.name as 'name', SalesTable.docdate, sum(SalesTable.[total Sales]) as 'Total Sales'
            from (
                select T0.basecard as 'name', t0.docdate, sum(T0.linetotal) as 'total Sales'
                from hmltd.dbo.inv1 t0
                left join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                where t1.U_BR = 'GPNA' and year(t0.docdate) = year(getdate()) 
                group by T0.basecard, T0.docDate
                union all
                select T0.basecard as 'name', t0.docdate, sum(t0.linetotal)*-1 as 'total Sales'
                from hmltd.dbo.rin1 t0
                left join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                where t1.U_BR = 'GPNA' and year(t0.docdate) = year(getdate()) 
                group by T0.basecard, T0.docDate
                ) SalesTable 
            group by SalesTable.name, SalesTable.DocDate
            )T3 on T0.cardcode = T3.name
--------INV + RIN------Credit + Debit Calculation In Between--------------------------------------INV + RIN------------------------------------
        where T0.U_CRR <> '' and t0.U_CR1 = 'R'
        group by t0.cardcode
    )DeltaWeekTable on DeltaMainTable.cardcode = DeltaWeekTable.cardcode and DeltaMainTable.weeks = DeltaWeekTable.maxweeks
    group by DeltaMainTable.descript
    )t0
left join
(select t2.descript, sum(T0.U_CG) as 'Annual Goal', sum(T0.U_NG) as 'Next Level Annual Goal'
from ocrd t0
left join OTER t2 on T0.territory = T2.territryID
where   T0.U_CRR <> '' and t0.U_CR1 = 'R'
Group by T2.descript
) t2 on t0.descript = t2.descript
order by t0.descript
```

This is the current result, deltas for this week which is week 43.

```
AL Delta    BC Delta    MS Delta    ONC Delta   ONE Delta   ONF Delta   ONN Delta   ONS Delta   ONW Delta   QCE Delta   QCW Delta                                                   
120906  41047   50600   100494  4518    8043    46748   79545   46619   30000   174553
```

what I want to do is create a table of deltas for every week of this year.  what I tried to do is add a while loop for this, but its give me the same result as it without the loop, so just 1 row of current week's deltas.

This is how I did it

```
declare @i int
declare @cnt int
set @i = 36 
set @cnt = datepart(ww, getdate())

while @i =< @cnt
begin

select 
-- Sales
    sum(case when T0.descript = 'AL' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'AL Total'  
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'BC' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'BC Total'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'MS' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'MS Total'  
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONC' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'ONC Total' 
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONE' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'ONE Total'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONF' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'ONF Total'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONN' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'ONN Total'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONS' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'ONS Total'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONW' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'ONW Total'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'QCE' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'QCE Total'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'QCW' then T0.[Current Sales] else Null end) as 'QCW Total'
--Current Delta
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'AL' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'AL Current Delta'  
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'BC' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'BC Current Delta'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'MS' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'MS Current Delta'  
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONC' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'ONC Current Delta' 
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONE' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'ONE Current Delta'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONF' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'ONF Current Delta'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONN' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'ONN Current Delta'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONS' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'ONS Current Delta'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'ONW' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'ONW Current Delta'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'QCE' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'QCE Current Delta'
    , sum(case when T0.descript = 'QCW' then T0.[Current Delta] else Null end) as 'QCW Current Delta'
from
    (select DeltaMainTable.descript,  sum(DeltaMainTable.Delta) as 'Current Delta', Sum(DeltaMaintable.[Yearly Sales]) as "Current Sales"
    from
    (
        select isnull(datepart(ww,T3.DocDate),0) as 'weeks'
        , t2.descript
        , t0.cardcode
        , sum(isnull(sum(t3.[total Sales]),0)) over (partition by t0.cardcode order by datepart(ww,T3.DocDate)) as 'Yearly Sales'
        , cast((case when min(t0.U_CG) - sum(isnull(sum(t3.[total Sales]),0)) over (partition by t0.cardcode order by datepart(ww,T3.DocDate)) > 0 then min(t0.U_CG) - sum(isnull(sum(t3.[total Sales]),0)) over (partition by t0.cardcode order by datepart(ww,T3.DocDate)) else 0 end) as int) as 'Delta'
        from 
        OCRD T0 
        left join oter T2 on T0.territory = T2.territryID
        left join 
--------INV + RIN------Credit + Debit Calculation In Between--------------------------------------INV + RIN------------------------------------
            (select SalesTable.name as 'name', SalesTable.docdate, sum(SalesTable.[total Sales]) as 'Total Sales'
            from (
                select T0.basecard as 'name', t0.docdate, sum(T0.linetotal) as 'total Sales'
                from hmltd.dbo.inv1 t0
                left join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                where t1.U_BR = 'GPNA' and year(t0.docdate) = year(getdate()) 
                group by T0.basecard, T0.docDate
                union all
                select T0.basecard as 'name', t0.docdate, sum(t0.linetotal)*-1 as 'total Sales'
                from hmltd.dbo.rin1 t0
                left join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                where t1.U_BR = 'GPNA' and year(t0.docdate) = year(getdate()) 
                group by T0.basecard, T0.docDate
            ) SalesTable 
            group by SalesTable.name, SalesTable.DocDate
            ) T3 on T0.cardcode = T3.name
--------INV + RIN------Credit + Debit Calculation In Between--------------------------------------INV + RIN------------------------------------
        where T0.U_CRR <> '' and t0.U_CR1 = 'R'
        group by t0.cardcode , t2.descript, datepart(ww, T3.DocDate)
    )DeltaMainTable
    inner join 
    (
        select
            t0.cardcode, ISNULL(max(datepart(ww,T3.DocDate)),0) as 'maxweeks'
        from 
        OCRD T0 
        left join 
--------INV + RIN------Credit + Debit Calculation In Between--------------------------------------INV + RIN------------------------------------
            (select SalesTable.name as 'name', SalesTable.docdate, sum(SalesTable.[total Sales]) as 'Total Sales'
            from (
                select T0.basecard as 'name', t0.docdate, sum(T0.linetotal) as 'total Sales'
                from hmltd.dbo.inv1 t0
                left join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                where t1.U_BR = 'GPNA' and year(t0.docdate) = year(getdate()) 
                group by T0.basecard, T0.docDate
                union all
                select T0.basecard as 'name', t0.docdate, sum(t0.linetotal)*-1 as 'total Sales'
                from hmltd.dbo.rin1 t0
                left join oitm t1 on t0.itemcode = t1.itemcode 
                where t1.U_BR = 'GPNA' and year(t0.docdate) = year(getdate()) 
                group by T0.basecard, T0.docDate
                ) SalesTable 
            group by SalesTable.name, SalesTable.DocDate
            )T3 on T0.cardcode = T3.name
--------INV + RIN------Credit + Debit Calculation In Between--------------------------------------INV + RIN------------------------------------
        where T0.U_CRR <> '' and t0.U_CR1 = 'R' and datepart(ww, T3.Docdate) =< @i
        group by t0.cardcode
    )DeltaWeekTable on DeltaMainTable.cardcode = DeltaWeekTable.cardcode and DeltaMainTable.weeks = DeltaWeekTable.maxweeks
    group by DeltaMainTable.descript
    )t0
left join
(select t2.descript, sum(T0.U_CG) as 'Annual Goal', sum(T0.U_NG) as 'Next Level Annual Goal'
from ocrd t0
left join OTER t2 on T0.territory = T2.territryID
where   T0.U_CRR <> '' and t0.U_CR1 = 'R'
Group by T2.descript
) t2 on t0.descript = t2.descript



set @i =  @i + 1
end;
```

This is my first time using a loop in sql.  Can someone tell me where I'm wrong?

I'm sorry for not been clear,
the expected output would be

```
Territory   AL Delta    BC Delta    MS Delta    ONC Delta   ONE Delta   ONF Delta   ONN Delta   ONS Delta   ONW Delta   QCE Delta   QCW Delta                                                   

Week43    120906    41047   50600   100494  4518    8043    46748   79545   46619   30000   174553
week42    120000    40000   50000   100000   4000    8000   40000   70000    46000   20000   170000
week41    3906    21047   1600    1494   518    43    6748    9545   6619    10000     14553
....
```

Delta of a territory at a specific week is calculated by adding up all the negative deltas of customers in that territory. so lets say there's only 2 people in one region.  First person in that region bought 40000 but the quota is only 30000 then the delta of that person is 0, and someone else bought 200 and his quota is 20000, the total delta is 19800.  We do not take the positive deltas into account. So each delta at a specific time frame is calculated taking the quota minus the current annual sales of each customer in each region with a minimum of 0 delta.  What I did in the first paragraph of code was to find this week's delta summary by taking the max() of documentation dates of all customers and calculate their running total sales up until their previous documentation date(Purchase date) and find their deltas.  So basically the first paragraph calculates Delta summary for today, but I need deltas up until last week, 2 weeks ago, 3 weeks ago, 4 weeks ago........

Any advise on how to do this without a loop?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Why are you using a loop here? I would say it went the wrong direction when you decided to make this your first loop.

Comment: This is a lot of code here to look through, but have you tried doing something like `GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, YourDateColumn)`?  There should be no reason to use a loop here at all.

Comment: I would be much easier to read your code if it was indented. This helps more than inserting a lot of empty lines.

Comment: @SeanLange Delta of a territory at a specific week is calculated by adding up all the negative deltas of customers in that territory. so lets say there's only 2 people in one region.  First person in that region bought 40000 but the quota is only 30000 then the delta of that person is 0, and someone else bought 200 and his quota is 20000, the total delta is 19800.  We do not take the positive deltas into account. So each delta at a specific time frame is calculated taking the quota minus the current annual sales of each customer in each region with a minimum of 0 delta.

Comment: @SeanLange  What I did in the first paragraph of code was to find this week's delta summary by taking the max() of documentation dates of all customers and calculate their running total sales up until their previous documentation date(Purchase date) and find their deltas.  So basically the first paragraph calculates Delta summary for today, but I need deltas up until last week, 2 weeks ago, 3 weeks ago, 4 weeks ago........

Any advise on how to do this without a loop?

Comment: This code is a complete mess.  You'd get better feedback by just adding your schema and some test data to your question.  There is definitely a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.  And I don't just mean the loop.

Answer (score 0):

No one is going try to understand such a mess. but loop are straight forward

Suggestion try to divide your code in small pieces so is easy to debug.

Start with something like this:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/UMABR30068)**

```
declare @i int
declare @cnt int
set @i = 0 
set @cnt = 10

While @i < @cnt
begin
    SELECT @i;
    set @i = @i+1;
end;
```